# sql server firewall ports

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Having trouble connecting to SQL Server 2012 through my router firewall.  I opened ports 2382 for the SQL Browser and 1433 for the SQL Server.  I can connect from the server to itself with the LAN IP address but not using the external router IP. I got some good info from this question.

[Opening ports for server instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539900/opening-ports-sql-server-instances)

I'm using the instance port they mentioned and it works also, but only if I connect from the server to itself using...

> Data Source=192.168.1.2,49867;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Characters;

I also can't connect from another PC on my LAN.  Which seems odd.  I have disabled the windows firewall on the server just in case.

Thanks for any info!

Comment: Have you checked Protocols for SQLSERVER instance & enabled client protocols in Configuration Manager?

Comment: By the way, just check the connection by command 'telnet server-ip 1433'. Could it be firewall or not?

Comment: Something with the router isn't allowing it, I tried telnet also, no connection.

Comment: telnet works from the local machine using **telnet 192.168.1.2 1433** but not from the other computer on my LAN

Comment: That's the problem! Because it seems to me SQL Srv doesn't control if you connect locally or remote since the the port listening. You have to look closer to the router settings. Maybe ports above 1024 dismissed or UDP should be enabled?!

Comment: 192.168.1.2 is equal to 127.0.0.1 in your case. Try to check any other service binded on port (http 80). If you have nothing but SQL Server, try any Windows-specific ports, say 135. It shouldn't connect remotely by default. Then enable it in firewall, check and switch back. Will the trick pass?

Comment: I mean router's internal firewall rules.

Comment: I got it to work, it seems I can't use the usual SQL Ports, the router or something doesn't like them, so instead of 1433 or even the instance port 49867 I had to use an 8000 port.  Not sure why but it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if "Allow remote connections to this server" is enabled under "Server Properties -> Connections" in SSMS